# How to create Period-Over-Period Insight To Display Last Two Completed Periods

Tags: amazon-quicksight

In Amazon Quicksight, you have the ability to create a "Period over Period" insight. This would, for example, show "Sales increase 10% from January 2020 to February 2020.

However, it seems that the "current" period is not configurable and always takes on the period a user would find themselves in. This means that the statistic is a little misleading since on January 2nd, it might say  "Sales decreased 89% from December 2019 to January 2020". While true, it's not apples to apples since January isn't finished yet.

Is there a way to have it compare the last two **completed** periods? For example, if January 2nd, it would compare November vs December?

Answer (score 0):

You should check on the following for the answer:
[amazon quicksights compare time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971901/amazon-quicksights-compare-time-periods)

Basically, if you want to calculate the 'price' (amount), then use the runningSum(sum()), and if it is a count of users, then use runningSum(count()).

```
runningSum(sum({sale price}),[truncDate("MM",{saleDate}) ASC], [truncDate("YYYY",{saleDate}])
```